# Is it safe to store dry, uncooked rice with cleaning products?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, rice, storage

So, I opened up a 30-lb bag of dry, uncooked jasmine rice last week in our outside shed / storage (apartment storage - it is dry, like an indoor closet but has an outdoor entrance).

I was in a hurry - screaming 2 year old competing for my attention - so after I took the amount of rice I needed, I rolled up the top of the bag and put it in a large plastic storage bin that happened to have some other cleaning products inside...

I'll admit not my finest moment, but my first concern was to stash it somewhere that 1. mice and 2. insects couldn't get to it. I think it was in there with Clorox wipes and windex.

Now DH thinks we should throw out all the rice because the bag was stored in an airtight container with chemicals. His concerns are 1. poisons in our food, and 2. will the rice taste weird if it absorbed odors.

I tend to agree but cringe to think we're throwing away $40 of rice... Advice?

Comment: Bleach fumes don't scare this chemist much, and the surfactants in Windex can't have too high a vapor pressure or they'd be gone before they get to your dirty windows. If this was only a few days, I wouldn't sweat it. You breath those fumes all the time anyway, and you are going to *boil* the rice. Several weeks? Then I'd dump.

Comment: That's an answer @WayfaringStranger

Comment: It's the health opinion of a purported chemist. I'm not comfortable calling that an answer, especially given the limits on "food safety" questions here.

Comment: Have you since moved the rice? How long was it in there? Does it smell weird?

Comment: The taste and not the safety is definitely the issue here. I’d just cook a small amount and taste it by itself before making a decision to throw the rest away. Get DH involved as your official taster (guinea pig) so he can’t harass you later!  PS: I bet you can’t taste it...